# pdb step into a function when already in pdb mode

Tags: python, pdb

When in pdb mode I often want to step into a function. Here is a situation that illustrates what I might do. Given the code:

```
def f(x):
    print('doing important stuff..')
    result = g(x) + 2
    return result

def g(x):
    print('some cool stuff going on here, as well')
    0 / 0  # oops! a bug
    return x + 5
```

Now, assume I set a breakpoint between the `print('doing important stuff...')` and `result = g(x) + 2`. So now, `f(x)` looks like this:

```
def f(x):
    print('doing important stuff..')
    __import__('pdb').set_trace()  # or something similar..
    result = g(x) + 2
    return result
```

And then I call the function `f(x)` with `x=5`, expecting to get a result `12`. When called, I end up in an interactive pdb session on the second line in `f`. Hitting `n` will give me the error (in this case a ZeroDivisionError). Now, I want to step into the `g(x)` function interactively to see what the error might be. Is it somehow possible to do that while not "moving" the breakpoint in `g(x)` and re-running everything? I simply want to enter the function `g` on the first line while still being in pdb mode.

I've searched for previous SO questions and answers + looked up the documentation and still haven't found anything that addresses this particular situation.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-step

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `s` command: it `s`-teps into the next function.

While in debugging mode, you can see all available commands using `h` (help). See also [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands).

Comment: Wow, that works! Guess that's me not being good enough at looking at the documentation. Cheers!

Comment: Guess it happens to everyone sometimes :p

Comment: The help informatin built in pdb is kind of confusing. [Python document site](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html?highlight=pdb#pdbcommand-step) says "... (either in a
function that is called or **on the next line** in the current function)", while the pdb help information says "either in a
function that is called or in the current function".